# Django - how i get instance from another function

Tags: django, django-views

I have two functions in views.py and I want when I submit first function another function to get instance from previous submitted function. How can I do that?

exemple models.py

```
class A(model.Models):
field1 = CharField()
field2 = CharField()

class B(model.Models):
field3 = CharField()
field4 = ForeignKey(A)
```

Comment: can you please share some code?

Comment: what code do you need ? the models?

Comment: You need to give us some clue about what you are doing. What are these functions? Are they views? How are they being called? Are they both in the same request, or in subsequent requests? What is this "instance" you are passing between them?

Comment: second model have a foreignkey to first model. I need to pass the id from first after i submit the form

Comment: Well, why not do that? This doesn't seem to have anything to do with passing instances between functions. If you're having problems, **show the views** with what you tried.

Comment: i cannot add both models in one function because second model is optional.  means that cannot add both in the same <form>(template)

Comment: What does that have to do with your previous comment? And why haven't you shown the views? (And why does the fact that the second model is optional mean that you can't add it in the same template?)

Answer (score 0):

first, you can store the response of the first function in a dictionary or list or any data structure. then use store response in another function.